# "Cannot get return value of a generator that hasn't returned " php backtracking

Tags: php, generator, schedule, backtracking

I am trying to do backtracking to solved a problem but I get this error:

[Error: genator hasn´t returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXdEq.png)

Fisrt I will introduce the main problem that the software must resolve:

> I have been trying to create the software for a hospital, this
>   software must create a schedule with the doctors for each day. Each
>   day must have 5 assigned doctors, one for a specialty called "trauma",
>   another for "ucr" and another for "box13".
>
> Before assigning doctors, the user must enter the number of holes of
>   each type that doctor can do that month. So I know how many "trauma",
>   "ucr" or "box13" have any doctor that month.
>
> Aaah! one more thing, you can not assign a doctor two days in a row.

So I decided to create a backtracking algorithm, the problem is that I am getting a Generator object at the end of the execution but I don´t get a valid return.

```
function bt($ps){
    if($ps->is_solution()){
        return $ps->get_solution();
    }
    else{   
        yield from $ps->successors();
    }
}


class Briker_vc_PS{
        public function __construct( $decisiones, $diasTotalFinal, $fechaInicio, $box13, $ucr, $trauma, $numGuardiasAsig){            
            $this->decisiones= $decisiones;
            $this->diasTotalFinal = $diasTotalFinal;
            $this->fechaInicio = $fechaInicio;
            $this->box13 = $box13;
            $this->ucr = $ucr;
            $this->trauma = $trauma;
            $this->numGuardiasAsig = $numGuardiasAsig;
        }   

        public function is_solution(){

            return $this->numGuardiasAsig == $this->diasTotalFinal*5;                
        }

        public function get_solution(){
            return $this->decisiones;
        }

        public function state(){ 
            return $this->decisiones[$this->fechaInicio];
        }

        public function  successors(){
            if( array_key_exists( $this->fechaInicio, $this->decisiones) == false ){
                $this->decisiones[$this->fechaInicio] = [];
            }

            if( array_key_exists( 'ids', $this->decisiones[$this->fechaInicio]) == false ){
                $this->decisiones[$this->fechaInicio]['ids'] = [];
            }


            if( array_key_exists( $this->fechaInicio ,$this->decisiones) and array_key_exists( 'box13' ,$this->decisiones) and array_key_exists( 'trauma' ,$this->decisiones) and array_key_exists( 'ucr' ,$this->decisiones)){
                if( (count($this->decisiones['trauma'])==1) and (count($this->decisiones['ucr'])==2) and (count($this->decisiones['box13'])==2) ){
                    $this->fechaInicio = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->fechaInicio." +1 day"));
                    $this->decisiones[$this->fechaInicio]['date'] = $this->fechaInicio;
                }               
            }

            $anterior = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->fechaInicio." -1 day"));

            $Lista=[];

            if( array_key_exists( 'trauma' ,$this->decisiones) == false ){
                foreach($this->trauma as $key => $val){
                    if( (in_array($key, $this->decisiones[$this->fechaInicio]['ids']) == false) and (in_array($key, $this->decisiones[$anterior]['ids']) == false) ){
                        $decisions= $this->decisiones;

                        $decisions[$this->fechaInicio]['trauma'] = [$key];
                        $auxtra= $this->trauma;

                        if($auxtra[$key] -1 == 0){
                            unset($auxtra[$key]);
                        }else{
                            $auxtra[$key] = $auxtra[$key] -1;
                        }

                        $num = $this->numGuardiasAsig +1 ;

                        $decisions[$this->fechaInicio]['ids'][] = $key;

                        yield from bt(new Briker_vc_PS( $decisions, $this->diasTotalFinal, $this->fechaInicio, $this->box13, $this->ucr, $auxtra, $num));

                    }
                }
            }

            if( (array_key_exists( 'box13' ,$this->decisiones) == false) or (count($this->decisiones['box13'])<2) ){
                foreach($this->box13 as $key => $val){
                    if( (in_array($key, $this->decisiones[$this->fechaInicio]['ids']) == false) and (in_array($key, $this->decisiones[$anterior]['ids']) == false) ){
                        $decisions= $this->decisiones;

                        if(array_key_exists( 'box13' ,$this->decisiones) == false){
                            $decisions[$this->fechaInicio]['box13'] = array();
                        }

                        $decisions[$this->fechaInicio]['box13'][] = $key;
                        $auxbox13= $this->box13;

                        if($auxbox13[$key] -1 == 0){
                            unset($auxbox13[$key]);
                        }else{
                            $auxbox13[$key] = $auxbox13[$key] -1;
                        }

                        $num = $this->numGuardiasAsig +1 ;

                        $decisions[$this->fechaInicio]['ids'][] = $key;

                        yield from bt( new Briker_vc_PS( $decisions, $this->diasTotalFinal, $this->fechaInicio, $auxbox13, $this->ucr, $this->trauma, $num));

                    }
                }
            }

            if( (array_key_exists( 'ucr' ,$this->decisiones) == false) or (count($this->decisiones['ucr'])<2) ){
                foreach($this->ucr as $key => $val){
                    if( (in_array($key, $this->decisiones[$this->fechaInicio]['ids']) == false) and (in_array($key, $this->decisiones[$anterior]['ids']) == false) ){
                        $decisions= $this->decisiones;

                        if(array_key_exists( 'ucr' ,$this->decisiones) == false){
                            $decisions[$this->fechaInicio]['ucr'] = array();
                        }   

                        $decisions[$this->fechaInicio]['ucr'][] = $key;
                        $auxucr= $this->ucr;

                        if($auxucr[$key] -1 == 0){
                            unset($auxucr[$key]);
                        }else{
                            $auxucr[$key] = $auxucr[$key] -1;
                        }

                        $decisions[$this->fechaInicio]['ids'][] = $key;

                        $num = $this->numGuardiasAsig +1 ;

                        yield from bt(new Briker_vc_PS( $decisions, $this->diasTotalFinal, $this->fechaInicio, $this->box13, $auxucr, $this->trauma, $num));

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        protected $GuardiasMedico;
        protected $decisiones;

 }
```

And this is the main program

```
      $month = $_REQUEST['mes'];
        $year = $_REQUEST['any'];

        $fecha_inicio = "01-".$month."-".$year;


 // fisrt i get the number of "trauma", "ucr" and "box13" for each doctor
// And i create a array with it with key the doctor_id

        $db = new SQLite3($dbname);

        $result = $db->query('SELECT m.id, m.nombre, m.apellido, mgm.ucr, mgm.trauma, mgm.box13 FROM medico AS m INNER JOIN MedicoGuardiaMes AS mgm ON m.id = mgm.doctor_id WHERE m.borrado = 0 AND mgm.mes = '.$month.' AND mgm.any = '.$year);


        $box13 = [];
        $ucr = [];
        $trauma = [];

        while($res = $result->fetchArray()){

            $box13[$res['id']] =  $res['box13'];
            $ucr[$res['id']] =  $res['ucr'];
            $trauma[$res['id']] =  $res['trauma'];

        }

        // I create the solution array and add the last day from the previous month

        $dataBaseDecisiones = [];

        $anterior = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fecha_inicio." -1 day"));

        $dataBaseDecisiones[$anterior] = [];
        $dataBaseDecisiones[$anterior]['ids'] = [];

        $diasTotalFinal=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);


       // Finally I create the initial object and starts the backtracking


        $initial_ps = new Briker_vc_PS($dataBaseDecisiones, $diasTotalFinal, $fecha_inicio, $box13, $ucr, $trauma, $numGuardiasAsig);

        var_dump(  bt($initial_ps)->getReturn() );
```

I don´t know why this code is not working or if I am using yield the right way.

Comment: I think this is a moment for you to take a tour and read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, especially the section https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (not my downvote btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that is reported happens because of the last line in your code:

```
bt($initial_ps)->getReturn();
```

When `bt` executes the `else` part it performs a recursive search until there is a `return`, and then it *yields* that value. But that does not finish the iterator's results and this yielded value is not considered the iterator's *return* value. So `getReturn()` triggers the exception you got.

You don't explain what you intend to get as output in that `var_dump`. If you want to output all the yielded results, then collect all those results first, for instance with `iterator_to_array`:

```
$iter = bt($initial_ps);
print_r(iterator_to_array($iter));
```

And only then you can execute:

```
print_r($iter->getReturn());
```

Comment: I only want the $ps which is solution, the array call decisiones. var_dump was because i wanted to know if the code were returning something